firebase storage download does not work using pyrebase
I am trying to read the list of files in firebase storage, determine what to download, and download the target. But neither reading file list nor downloading file works.
First, I tried to get the list of storage :
storage = firebase.storage()
print(storage.child('version').list_files()

and got the error message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bboyc\PycharmProjects\pymoonchild\.venv\checkRecentVersion.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(storage.child('version').list_files())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bboyc\PycharmProjects\pymoonchild\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 539, in list_files
    return self.bucket.list_blobs()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Storage' object has no attribute 'bucket'

I searched a little bit and it seems that I should use service account or something, and decided to not use it since what I am now building is for public distribution app.
Next I tried to make direct downloading code :
storage.child('version/test0.14.1.zip').download(path='',filename='test.zip')


And no error appeared, but the file download also did not get processed .
Youtube and stackOverflow search result did not work for me. Now I am lost. I don't think that it is matter of permission, since No permission error did not appeared .
What am I missing ?

It was my dumb at setting permission at firestore storage.
match /version/{allPaths=**}{
      allow read;
    }

You must be careful when adding / .
